# Migrating from Access 2000/2003 to Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, migration, compatibility, ms-access-2003, ms-access-2010

I want to use access 2000 and 2003 databases in access 2010. Since I don't want to check if everythings's working manually I am looking for a tool that analyzes VBA code for errors or compatibility issues that occur using access 2010 (or if available at least access 2007).

Comment: I don't have access 2010 installed locally so I can't do that. Since I still need access 2003, and I've read about problems with installing two versions of access.

Comment: A customer is planning to upgrade to Access 2010 and I assume my code won't be completely compatible. I developed this specific application in access 2003, my client used access 2000 and there have also been some compatibility issues. Since I dont have access 2010 I'd like to continue developing in 2003 and still be able to check if it will work in 2010.

Comment: I was hoping some tool may exist and I could avoid installing a VM, but I guess that's the best solution anyway.

Comment: Running both versions of Access is no problem. Give Acc2k3 elevated rights and it's even smoother. Only drawback is the windows installer, which comes every time you start 2010.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [utility here](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueChecker.html) and [explanations here](http://allenbrowne.com/Access2007.html).
And the enternal refrain: COMPILE ! Before and after migrating.

Comment: thanks, thats a useful tool, although it does not analyze the code for issues.