# Migrate from Access 2003 ADP to Access 2007(2010) ADP

Tags: ms-access, adp

How can I do this? Is it possible with no pain? I got nothing specific when I ask Google and search on SO. I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688802/migrating-from-access-2000-2003-to-access-2010) too but not sure that it comparable with my case.

Comment: ADP is a dead end, it's no longer supported after Access 2010. So the best thing to do is to convert it to .accdb, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19807031/how-to-convert-an-adp-to-accdb-using-access-2013

Answer (score 0):

An Access 2003 ADP project should work ok with Access 2007 or 2010. It won't work with 2013 or newer, though -- you will need to make a new .accdb database and link to the SQL data, then import the forms, reports & modules into the new .accdb file.